# url response time tracker in c++

Tags: c++

i have to develop a program that would keep track of all access url in a browser with its response time. the program must not be browser-dependent.

any suggestion on topics that need to be studied? or anything helpful?
thanks for the time!:)

Comment: It's not clear if this is hoping to somehow tap into the browser's operations, measure from within a particular website, or maybe from somewhere between the browser and server.

Comment: well, this programs runs somewhere between the browser and the server.  it records all url accessed on the client-side.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you could write a small redirector (a mini-proxy) that intercepts and times traffic to and from the browser.

Have the browser use the redirector rather than a direct internet connection.